# R help: keep top n entries per column

Tags: r, matrix

Again I'm stuck on matrix manipulations that could probably solved with apply or a loop.
I have a large data frame from which I would like to keep a certain number n of the highest values per column. But the dimensions of the data frame should not be changed. So I thought it's a good idea do it like that:
1. Find the nth highest number per column with (in this case: third highest, figured out with help of other posts)

```
x <- c(0.2, 0.23, 0.35, 0.56, 0.12, 0.7, 0, 0.66, 0.45, 0.21, 0.49, 0.47, 0.1, 0.63, 0.55)
m <- matrix(data = x, nrow=4, ncol = 4)
>m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.20 0.12 0.45 0.47
[2,] 0.23 0.70 0.21 0.10
[3,] 0.35 0.00 0.49 0.63
[4,] 0.56 0.66 0.43 0.55

m.low <- apply(m, 2, function(i) sort(i)[ dim(m)[1]-2])
```

2. replace all values below the one in m.low with 0, done per column. This is where I don't know how to go on... 
The desired output should look something like this:

```
 > m.new
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.00 0.12 0.45 0.47
[2,] 0.23 0.70 0.00 0.00
[3,] 0.35 0.00 0.49 0.63
[4,] 0.56 0.66 0.43 0.55
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me and add some explanation of the function to the post. Also, there might be an easier way without finding the nth value first.
Thanks!

*Edited m for better reproducibility and added m.new as desired output. Sorry!

Comment: `rnorm(16)` isn't reproducible without `set.seed` it will also help if you'd add your desired output, as this question not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `apply` with "MARGIN=2" to loop over the columns of `m`.  The below code is similar to the one you used for "m.low" except that it is using `replace` function to replace the elements in each column based on the condition argument `i < sort(i)..` to 0.

```
apply(m, 2, function(i) replace(i, i<sort(i)[ dim(m)[1]-2],0))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 0.00 0.12 0.45 0.47
#[2,] 0.23 0.70 0.00 0.00
#[3,] 0.35 0.00 0.49 0.63
#[4,] 0.56 0.66 0.43 0.55
```

Or from the `m.low`

```
m[m <m.low[col(m)]] <- 0
```

Or create the "indx" using `ave`

```
indx <- !!ave(m, col(m), FUN=function(i) i <sort(i)[dim(m)[1]-2])
m[indx] <- 0
```

Or you can convert the `m` to "data.frame" and use `mutate_each/replace` combo

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(m) %>% 
            mutate_each(funs(replace(., .<sort(.)[2], 0)))
```

Comment: The apply works like a charm, still trying to get the second option to work on my own data...

Answer (score 2):

```
f <- function(vec){
  bound = sort(vec)[length(vec)-2]
  vec[which(vec<bound)] = 0
  vec
}
res <- apply(m,2,f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `mapply`.  To make it work, it needs to recognize each column as its own element, which is why I use the somewhat kludgy `as.list(as.data.frame())`:

```
mapply( m.low, as.list(as.data.frame(m)), FUN = function(low,col) {
  col[ col < low ] <- 0
  col
} )
```